# My java program keeps on freezing

Tags: java, swing, freeze

I have tried to narrow this down a bit but my program keeps on freezing at the bit of code:

```
try {
    MainMenu.start();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    System.out.print(e1.getCause());
}
```

I type a couple of random lines in the JTextField, press enter and then the program freezes.

Here is the whole code if you need it.

```
package Main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class window extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7092006413113558324L;
private static int NewSize;
public static String MainInput;
public static JTextField input = new JTextField(10);
public static JTextArea output = new JTextArea(main.Winx, NewSize);

public window() {
    super("Satine");
    NewSize = main.Winy - 20;
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    output.setToolTipText("");
    add(input, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    add(output, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    input.addKeyListener(this);
    input.requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        String MainInput = input.getText();
        try {
            MainMenu.start();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.print(e1.getCause());
        }
        output.append(MainInput + "\n");
        input.setText("");
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}
}
```

Thank you for taking time out to assess this.

Also i forgot here is MainMenu.java

```
package Main;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class MainMenu {
public static String InputText = window.MainInput;
public static String CompleteInput, noCaseCompleteInput, A1, A2, A3, A4,
        A5; // Command
// Inputs
public static String Advance = "Y";
public static String Advance2 = "Y";
public String Command;
public static String CorrectP;
public static StringTokenizer st;

public static void start() throws IOException{
    window.output.append("Satine. /InDev-01/ " + "\n");
    do {
        CompleteInput = InputText;
        noCaseCompleteInput = CompleteInput.toLowerCase();
        st = new StringTokenizer(noCaseCompleteInput);
        switch (st.nextToken()) {
        case "help":
            helpData.HelpDefine();
            continue;
        case "end":
            System.exit(0);
        case "newworld":
            newWorldRun.NewWorld();
            break;
        case "save":
            Save.SaveFull();
            continue;
        case "load":
            Save.FileName = st.nextToken();
            Read.ReadFull();
            continue;
        case "profile":
            profileData.profile();
            break;
        case "dp":
            debugPrint.print();
            continue;
        case "move":
            Movement.MoveCommand();
            continue;
        case "equip":
            equip.equip();
            break;
        case "attack":
            MonsterEvents.attackStart();
            break;
        default:
            window.output.append("Please Enter A Valid Command" + "\n");
            System.out.println("Please Enter A Valid Command");
        }
        window.input.setText("");
        } while (Advance.equals("Y"));
    }
   }
```

Comment: Where is the code for `MainMenu`?

Comment: Or at least tell us what MainMenu is and does

Comment: Do you want to share that class? Secret?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Dude, don't give out the code!!!  It's a trap!!!!!

Comment: `System.out.print(e1.getCause());` Should be `e1.printStackTrace();` to get best information.

Comment: Why don't you respect naming conventions? This makes your code very hard to read.

Comment: @JB Nizet Agreed. I die a little inside when I see `private static int NewSize;`

Comment: I just don't get it. "my code breaks HERE -> <unknown suspicious looking method call with no information on what it does>" -- Nobody is that good to where they can debug that

Comment: For future reference, regarding naming conventions: `ClassNamesAreTitleCase` (including enums, interfaces, annotations), `CONSTANTS_ARE_ALL_CAPS`, and `everythingElseIsCamelCase`.

Comment: Note: Thanks WChargin, ill try and get into a habit of that also i added mainmenu.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String MainInput = input.getText();` shadows the object instance variable `MainInput` and hence is not used in `MainMenu.start()`. Also, if `MainMenu.Advance` is not set to a value other than `Y`, it'll endlessly loop.